# How to make a call to a template function less verbose

Tags: c++, templates

There is a function

```
template <class ...T>
void foo(std::function<void(T...)> callback);
```

into which I pass a callback.

I'd like to do something like

```
foo(bar);
```

where `bar` is, for example,

```
void bar(int a, long b, double c, float d);
```

but that gives me

```
error: no matching function for call to bar(void (&)(int, long int, double, float))
```

I have to call `foo` as

```
foo(std::function<void(int, long, double, float)>(bar));
```

which is too verbose. Even

```
foo<int, long, double, float>(bar);
```

would have been better.

```
foo(bar);
```

would be just ideal.

Anyway, how can I make calls to `foo` to be less verbose?

**Edit:** declaration of `foo` has to stay the same.

Comment: `foo<int, long, double, float>(bar)` should work (note that you used the wrong types in your Q). Are you sure it does not? Can you also show how you eventually use this callback? Perhaps passing it without coercion to `std::function` could be a solution.

Comment: I can't see a use case for that, because a template can not call the function without any knowledge of the parameters content. If the template only forwards the function, the target for this template also has to handle it. Can you give us a real world use case for that problem? My idea is, that you can make the template parameters visible from the knowledge of how to use them in the template.

Comment: what is wrong with `template <class F> void foo(F callback);` ? you avoid your problems and don't pay for the type-erasure

Comment: Oh, right, I will fix the types. Copy-pasted from the original code, when I used different ones in SO example. @Angew it doesn't work, barks `error: no matching function for call` at me.

Comment: @PiotrS. I have to use `std::function`, my program's logic with variadic-template hell depends on it.

Comment: @VanillaGorilla please mention that you cannot change the declaration of `foo` in the question, as otherwise there are many possibilities

Comment: @VanillaGorilla variadic templates are there to help you, not to make your code verbose

Comment: @PiotrS. they help me alright, have no doubt in that! In fact, that `foo` function splits a buffer filled with network-received data into chunks of bytes, such that each chunk is `sizeof` of each of its variadic arguments  and applies those chunks as `callback`'s arguments, calling `callback` with them! So the way we split the network buffer depends only on `callback`'s signature! Such madness is only possible with variadic templates! (Oh, and don't worry, I have some type-safety mechanism on top of that). It's just that I wanted to make a function call a little less verbose/explicit.

Comment: @Klaus my comment above describes the use-case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd write a wrapper function that translates the function pointer into a `std::function` wrapper:

```
template <typename... T>
void foo(std::function<void (T...)> f) {}

template <typename... T>
void foo(void (*f)(T...)) {
    foo(std::function<void (T...)>(f));
}
```

`foo()` can then be called either way:

```
void bar(int,double) {}

void foo_caller() {
    foo(std::function<void (int,double)>(bar));
    foo(bar);
}
```

**Addendum:** Non-static member function wrapper

Same approach can be used for pointer-to-member functions — just add another overload:

```
template <typename C,typename... T>
void foo(void (C::*f)(T...)) {
    foo(std::function<void (C *,T...)>(f));
}
```

Note the extra first parameter for the `this` pointer for the member function. Usage is similar:

```
struct quux {
    void mf(char *,double) {}
};

void foo_caller() {
    foo(&quux::mf);
}
```

Comment: Any way to make this work if `bar` is a non-static class method?

Answer (score 1):

In case your `foo` definition is not set in stone, can change it to

```
#include <functional>

template <class Ret, class ...T>
void foo(Ret callback(T... params))
{
}

void bar(int a, long b, double c, float d){}

int main() 
{
    foo(bar);
}
```

Comment: this is not what OP is asking for

Comment: @PiotrS. I though that's exactly what OP asked, didn't say anything about keeping the declaration of `foo` fixed.

Comment: now he/she did, and you suggest that adding a return type is the solution, which is rather irrelevant to actual question

Answer (score 1):

If you know you will pass a plain *function pointer* to `foo`, and not just any C++11 lambda, you can redefine `foo` as:

```
template <class ...T>
void foo(void(*callback)(T...)) {
   // .....
}
```

If you want to support lambdas, you can be more generic with the type

```
template <class LambdaType>
void foo(LambdaType callback) {
   // .....
}
```

the downside of this approach is that if you pass something that is not a function or lambda, you will get weird template error messages coming from inside of `foo`.

---

With your original solution the compiler has problems matching `T...` to `int, long, double, float`, probably because it is a nested type.

If I told you to match `void(int, double)` to `MyTempalte<T...>` you wouldn't know that I intend to replace `T...` with `int, double`, because you don't know what `MyTemplate` does with its arguments. Maybe `MyTemplate` is doing something weird to its template arguments first?

Same, the compiler doesn't know how to match `std::function` template parameters to your function pointer.