# How to make constructor accepting std::function also accept method pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

Say I have

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(std::function<void(std::string)> callback1,
        std::function<void(int)> callback2) :
        callback1(callback1), callback2(callback2)
    {
    }

private:
    std::function<void(std::string)> callback1;
    std::function<void(int)> callback2
}
```

I can easily construct it in the case I'm using plain functions

```
void callback1Handler(std::string)
{
    // i'm a potato
}

void callback2Handler(int)
{
    // i'm a teapot
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo(callback1Handler, callback2Handler);

    return 0;
}
```

But if I'm using a class, then things get complicated.

I'd like to be able to do something like  [the **Addendum** of this answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28937835/4648841)

```
class Main
{
public:
    Main()
    {
        Foo foo(&Main::callback1Handler, &Main::callback2Handler);
    }

    void callback1Handler(std::string)
    {
        // i'm a potato
    }

    void callback2Handler(int)
    {
        // i'm a teapot
    }
}
```

But that obviously wouldn't compile. To make it work one would need to use either `std::bind` or lambdas, or something else.

I want to try to avoid the ugliness of `std::bind(&Main::callbackNHandler, this, std::placeholders::_1, ..., std::placeholders::_N)`, which is mostly the ugliness of having those placeholders explicitly specified.

Using lambdas as `[=](std::string str){callbackNHandler(str);}` is also ugly, because you have to specify every single variable the callback accepts.

It would be great if I could just use `&Main::callback1Handler`, just like in the `Main` class example, or `&Main::callback1Handler, this`, which is a bit more flexible, since you can specify the instance pointer of `Main`.

Note that `Foo` constructor has to remain the same and `callback1`&`callback2` member variables have to also remain the same. However, you may overload `Foo` constructor, making the overload convert method pointers (or whatever else you will make it to accept) into `std::function`s and store them in `callback1`&`callback2`.

Answer (score 4):

```
template<class T, class R, class...Args>
std::function<R(Args...)> method( T* t, R(T::*m)(Args...) ){
  return [=](Args&&...args)->R{
    return (t->*m)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  };
}
```

then `method( instance, &Main::callback1Handler )` should work, up to typos.

It gets simpler in C++14.

The above does needless type erasure: a helper type instead of a lambda lets you avoid that.

```
template<class T, class Sig>
struct method_t;
template<class T, class R, class... Args>
struct method_t<T,R(Args...)> {
  T* t;
  R(T::*m)(Args...);
  template<class...Ts>
  R operator()(Ts&&...ts)const{
    return (t->*m)(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
};

template<class T, class R, class...Args>
method_t<T, R(Args...)> method( T* t, R(T::*m)(Args...) ){
  return {t, m};
}
```

with the same signature.  It can even be stored in a `std::function<R(Args...)>`.  The advantage of the above is that there is no needless overhead if the signature of the `std::function` does not exactly match, or if you don't use a `std::function` at all.

The downside is 3x as much code.

In C++14 we can simply do:

```
template<class T, class R, class...Args>
auto method( T* t, R(T::*m)(Args...) ){
  return [=](auto&&...args)->R{
    return (t->*m)(decltype(args)(args)...);
  };
}
```

which is as brief as the first one, and as powerful as the second one.

Comment: So, will this work in C++11? Not sure if variadic templates in lambdas work in C+11.

Comment: @VanillaGorilla Yes.  The lambda isn't variardic despite the `...` -- each lambda has a fixed set of parameters.  But a different lambda is generated based on the variardic types in the enclosing function template.  Anyhow, added a more efficient/more code version, and a C++14 version that is as efficient, but almost the same code load as the first example.  The C++14 one is a variardic lambda with auto parameters, in comparison to the C++11 solution at the top.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the signature of the std::function does not exactly match"? Don't we want the signature of `callbackNHandler` to always match the one of `std::function` and let the compilation fail otherwise? I don't see why would we want to accept types that don't exactly match and how would that even be possible -- doesn't `std::function` require the types of the method we wrap to match with its own types?

Comment: `std::function<int(int)> x = std::function<double(double)>{}` is a legal assignment: on some compilers it may issues warnings from the generated `double` to `int` conversion.  `std::function` will accept anything compatible (convert-from its args type, convert-return-to its return type), not just exact matches. So a `std::function<int(int)>` wrapping of a lambda will result in a `std::function<double(double)>` containing a type-erased `std::function<int(int)>`, which contains the lambda.  Had you passed the lambda directly, we would get `std::function<double(double)>` wrapped around the lambda

Comment: "It can even be stored in a `std::function<R(Args...)>`". Maybe it can, but it doesn't automatically convert to one though. `template <class ...T> void Bar::foo(std::function<void(T...)> f);` called as `foo(method(this, &Main::callbackNHandler));` gives `error: no matching function for call to 'Bar::foo(method_t<Main, void(int, float, double)>)'` `candidate is:` `template<class ... T> void Bar::foo(std::function<void(T ...)>)` `note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:` `note:   'method_t<Main, void(int, float, double)>' is not derived from 'std::function<void(T ...)>'`

Comment: @vani that is not conversion, that is template argument pattern matching.  Completely different thing with a different purpose.  There is nealy zero reason to ever pattern match on a `std::function` signature: doing so is a sign your code has issues.  The called function should be a fixed signature `std::function`, or just `F`, in 999/1000 cases.

Comment: Well, my library has a `uint8_t` buffer filled with network data. It reads 1st byte, which is message id, and then calls user's callback with the message id. Based on the message id, user calls `accept` (the `foo`), passing a function into it. The library then splits the network buffer into chunks of bytes based on the `sizeof` of each of the arguments the user-passed function accepts. Then the library applies those chunks as the user-passed function's arguments, calling the user-passed function, so that the user gets the data that was sent over the network.

Comment: The library works only with fixed-width primitive types and floats/doubles. The library handles host-to-network and the other way around byte order conversions automatically. It's just that in my project I have to define many different messages that can be sent over the network, and doing ntoh, hton conversions and memcpy into/from the network buffer manually for every single message type was too tedious for me. That way all of that is done for me automatically, I just need to make sure the argument types for each message match on both ends, which can be done with some shared header file.

Comment: @vani that header file (common) should dictate the signatures.  Not the type of the function/method that consumes the message.  Check for compatibility at the consuming end, not define parsing based off consuming function.  Serialization and deserialization should depend on the same header file.

Comment: Right, function signatures, that's what I meant. `#define MSG_COORDINATES dobule, double` and `#define MSG_COORDINATES_ID 1` in the common header fine, then the receiver forward declares (in a header of a class, presumably) `void onCoordinatesReceived(MSG_COORDINATES);` and later defines it `void onCoordinatesReceived(double x, double y) { /* do stuff */ }` and passes a pointer to this function to the network library when the library indicates that it received message id == MSG_COORDINATES_ID. Sender sends like `send<MSG_COORDINATES>(MSG_COORDINATES_ID, 10.2, 15.3);`.

Comment: Does my code have issues or it's one of those rare 1/1000 cases? :-) Personally I'm pretty happy with it. One of requirements I had was reduced network usage, so I don't send information about data types (otherwise I would just use ASN.1 or protobuf for serialization/deserialization), only message id, total size of the following data and the data. I do check on the receiver side that sum of `sizeof` of all arguments the user-specified function has adds up to the size of the message we got over the network. That's the only "check for compatibility" I can do "at the consuming end" (quoting you).

Comment: `template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};template<class Sig>struct sig;template<class R, class...Args>struct sig<R(Args...)>{using result=R;using args=types<Args...>;}; template<size_t> struct message {}; template<> struct message<0>:sig<void(double,double)>{};` is a reflection-enabled way to define that message `0` has two arguments, `double,double`, and returns `void`.  `send<MSG_COORDINATES>(3.14,2)` can lookup `message<0>`, bundle the arguments into a pair of doubles, dispatch over wire.  Reciever map populated with `std::function` built from `message<0>` and a callable.

Answer (score 2):

> Using lambdas as `[=](std::string str){callbackNHandler(str);}` is also ugly, because you have to specify every single variable the callback accepts.

C++14 generic lambdas solve that problem:

```
[this](auto... args){ callback1Handler(args...); }
```

For C++11 you could write a simple utility that can be used like so:

```
    Foo foo(simple_bind(&Main::callback1Handler, this),
            simple_bind(&Main::callback2Handler, this));
```

That would be defined as a function template like this:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
SimpleBinder<T, F>
simple_bind(F T::* memfn, T* that)
{ return { that, memfn }; }
```

Where the type `SimpleBinder<T, F>` is just:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
struct SimpleBinder
{
  T* m_this;
  F T::*  m_memfn;

  template<typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args&&... args)
    { (m_this->*m_memfn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};
```

This isn't a fully generic utility (for example, it doesn't do anything with the return type of the member function, always returning `void`, but that is OK for your requirements, where both the `std::function` objects return `void` anyway), but it solves the problem of associating an arbitrary member function with a `this` pointer, and then calling it with some set of arguments.

Although the `SimpleBind` object appears to accept any arguments, in fact you'll get a nasty compiler error if you try to call it with arguments that aren't compatible with the member function it binds. Again, that's not a problem, because the `std::function` objects you store it in will ensure that only the right type of arguments are ever passed to it.